# Comparing ITables after test

Tags: testing, dbunit, itable

I need to compare table contents described in xml file to actual database table contents.

What I have so far is

```
ITable actualTable = Iconnection.createQueryTable("query for actual contents here!");
    IDataSet expectedDataSet = builder.build(file.xml"));
    expectedReplacementDataSet = new ReplacementDataSet(expectedDataSet);
    expectedReplacementDataSet.addReplacementObject("[variable_the test_puts_to_database]", variable);
    ITable expectedTable = expectedReplacementDataSet.getTable("table");
```

Asserting the two Itables fail, because expectedTable does not hold table metadata. The contents match. I don't want to set dtd metadata to builder object. Any way to get though this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer myself. The assertion needs to be dbunit Assertion.assertEquals, not junit Assert.AssertEquals